# QString to boost::filesystem::path converion issues for SOME special characters

Tags: c++, qt, boost, stdstring

On windows, I am facing a string conversion issue for ONLY SOME special characters when I try to convert a `filepath` from `QString` to `boost::filesystem::path`. I get the input QString from a typical QDialog. The consequence is that, the `boost::filesystem::exists( path )` FAILS even though the file exists.

I used the following library functions to do the conversion:

To convert from QString to `std::string` I am using:

```
QString::toUtf8()   (Qt 4.8)
```

To convert from `std::string` to `boost::filesystem::path` I am using:

```
boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<wchar_t>()
```

This is how I pass the file name to QDialog:

Bad case: I copy some special characters from an MS WORD document (it looks something like `ßçâäëüûéàè.pdf`) and paste. The `boost::filesystem::exists( path )` FAILS. (Is there a way to attached MS WORD here?)

Good case: I copy same special characters from windows explorer (characters from an actual existing file with these special characters) and paste. The `boost::filesystem::exists( path )` succeeds.

Comment: "Is there a way to attached MS WORD here?" Why would you want to do that? The origin of the characters is *irrelevant*. You can't attach MS WORD files here precisely so that people don't do what you wished to do. We'd have to open a word file just to extract a few characters. That's a big waste of time and resources.

Comment: Try `QString::toStdWString()` instead. You then don't have to do the `utf_to_utf` conversion, you can simply pass the wide string as a path constructor.

Comment: I feel QString::toUtf8() is buggy. The String::toStdWString() also gives the same end result -> failure of boost::filesystem::exists( path ).

Comment: `QString::toUtf8` is not buggy - those conversions are unit-tested and it'd be a big deal if they were incorrect for rather basic latin-1 characters. I can't wrap my head around how `boost::filesystem::path` works - their documentation is horrendous, and nobody writes what are the semantics of the individual constructors etc. My best recommendation would be to dump that part boost, frankly said. Imbued locale, my goodness. It seems to be a royal mess.